# Mysql VARCHAR to CHAR conversion behavior question

Tags: mysql

I'm looking at this Mysql question [link](http://dba.fyicenter.com/Interview-Questions/MySQL/When_you_create_a_table_and_then_run_SHOW_CREAT.html):

And I can't repeat the behavior described in the answer to that question.

I tried creating tables with CHAR and VARCHAR column of various lengths and it doesn't matter what length - SHOW CREATE TABLE always return the data type that I've originally defined.

So - no CHAR->VARCHAR switching is going on.

Is answer to the question below only partially correct (I'm talking only about items 1 and 2)?

---

Q:
When you create a table, and then run SHOW CREATE TABLE on it, you occasionally get different results than what you typed in. What does MySQL modify in your newly created tables?

A (supposedly):

1. VARCHARs with length less than 4 become CHARs
2. CHARs with length more than 3 become VARCHARs.
3. NOT NULL gets added to the columns declared as PRIMARY KEYs
4. Default values such as NULL are specified for each column

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That question is pretty old, written back in the days of MySQL 4.

As of MySQL 5.0, 1 & 2 from that list are no longer true.

Answer (score 3):

There is a page in the MySQL's manual that answers some of your questions : [**12.1.14.2. Silent Column Specification Changes**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/silent-column-changes.html).

Quoting some portions that correspond to items you posted in your question :

For **item 3** :

> Columns that are part of a `PRIMARY
>   KEY` are made `NOT NULL` even if not
>   declared that way.

About the **size of varchar** columns *(not exactly one of your items, though)* :

> If strict SQL mode is not enabled, a
>   VARCHAR column with a length
>   specification greater than `65535` is
>   converted to `TEXT`, and a `VARBINARY`
>   column with a length specification
>   greater than `65535` is converted to
>   `BLOB`. Otherwise, an error occurs in
>   either of these cases.

And that page ends with the following sentence :

> To see whether MySQL used a data type
>   other than the one you specified,
>   issue a `DESCRIBE` or `SHOW CREATE
>   TABLE` statement after creating or
>   altering the table.

So I'm guessing you might expect some additional differences, that are not listed.

---

Doing a quick test, here's a `create table` statement :

```
create table test_2 (
    id int primary key, 
    blah_vc varchar(2), 
    blah_c char(5)
) engine=InnoDb;
```

And the table that's created gives :

```
mysql> desc test_2;
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id      | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| blah_vc | varchar(2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| blah_c  | char(5)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table test_2;
+--------+--------------------------------------------+
| Table  | Create Table                               |
+--------+--------------------------------------------+
| test_2 | CREATE TABLE `test_2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `blah_vc` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `blah_c` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+--------+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So :

1. no : `varchar` has not been transformed to `char`
2. no : `char` has not been transformed to `varchar`
3. yes : `not null` has been added to `primary key`

   - well, that one is funny : describe says it hasn't,
   - but show create table indicates it has...
   - Anyway : it makes sense, for a primary key column, to not be nullable.
4. yes : `null` is specified as default for columns that can be null.

Comment: thanks for this answer. however -i was a bit unclear with my question. I do know that 3 and 4 are correct. I only unsure about 1 and 2. So far it seems that 1 and 2 are incorrect.

Comment: I did some test *(I'll edit my answer to post those)*, and I arrive to the same conclusion as you.